# Apache Camel : set property and getter

Tags: xml, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am using apache camel.
I use setProperty but now i have errors when i am getting it.

Set

```
  <setProperty propertyName="ExportFileName">
    <camel:simple>${date:now:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}</camel:simple>
  </setProperty>
```

Get

```
<to uri="file:{{order.dir}}?fileName=exportOrders_{{ExportFileName}}.csv&amp;charset=utf-8&amp;fileExist=Append" />
```

I used to get the variable like these ways -> `{{ExportFileName}} , ${ExportFileName}, {ExportFileName}` but it caused errors.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `${exchangeProperty.ExportFileName}`. Double braces `{{}}` are usually used to fetch properties from config/property-placeholder files.